# Concurrent execution of UPDATE statements in java

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream, completable-future

I have a list of objects for which I submit an update DB statement as below.

Current code:

```
List<MyObj> updateObj = ....<logic here>;
updateObj.stream().forEach(obj -> updateMyDB(obj));
```

Here each obj is getting executed sequentially and taking more time. Now I wish to parallelize it. What is the best way to do this?

Option 1:

```
updateObj.parallelStream().foreach(obj->updateMyObj(obj));
```

Option 2:

```
ExecutorService executor = new FixedThreaadPool(10);
updateObj.stream().foreach(obj -> completableFuture.runAsync(()-> updateMyObj(obj),executor));
```

Intention here is to parallize operations. Any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: By using a batch update method of the form `updateMyObjects(List<MyObj> objects)`. Databases aren't used with the kind of parallelization that you're suggesting.

Comment: I don't know what framework you use... JPA? if it is slow, google for batch updates/inserts

Comment: First of all you would need to investigate whether the JDBC driver supports multi-threading. Then, as said by the other commenters, submitting statements in parallel is unlikely to gain any performance. You can’t solve database performance problems with Collections concurrency.